# onLocationChanged() is not getting executed in my service

Tags: android, gps, salesforce, android-service

i'm trying to automatically update my location and have some other part of cloud related code working when location is changed. here is the code of my service:

```
    package com.salesforce.samples.templateapp;

import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;

import com.salesforce.androidsdk.app.ForceApp;
import com.salesforce.androidsdk.rest.RestClient;
import com.salesforce.androidsdk.rest.RestRequest;
import com.salesforce.androidsdk.rest.RestResponse;
import com.salesforce.androidsdk.rest.RestClient.AsyncRequestCallback;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.GpsStatus.Listener;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyServices extends Service {
    RestClient client;
    double plat;
    double plong;
    int Two_Min=2*60*1000;

    // TextView infoText;

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Location Updation has started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        Log.v("X","Response:in onStartCommand()");
        //Intent in = new Intent().setClass(MyServices.this, GPSUpdate.class);
            //in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            //startActivity(in);
        detectLocation();
                return START_STICKY;


    }

    private void detectLocation() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(this, "Inside detectlocation()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        LocationManager lm1 = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener ll1 = new MyLocationListetner();

        Criteria crit = new Criteria();
        crit.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        String best = lm1.getBestProvider(crit, false);
       // lm1.requestLocationUpdates(best, 0, 1, ll1);
        Log.v("X",
                "Response:After creating lm and ll ");

    //  boolean b1=lm1.addGpsStatusListener((Listener) ll1);
        //Log.v("X",
            //  "Response: "+b1);

        lm1.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, ll1);
        Log.v("X",
                "Response:After lm1.requestLocationUpdates ");


        /*Location loc = null;
        loc.getLatitude();
        loc.getLongitude();
        Log.v("X","Response:"+loc);
        ll1.onLocationChanged(loc);*/
    }

    class MyLocationListetner implements LocationListener {


        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d("X","Response:inside onLocationChanged ");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "inside onLocationChanged()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //Log.v("X","Response:"+location);
            if (location != null) {
                plat = location.getLatitude();
                plong = location.getLongitude();
                Log.d("X",
                        "Response:Location " + Double.toString(plat)+Double.toString(plong));

                String objectType = "akshayg__User__c";
                String objectId = "a02900000089fK3";
                HashMap<String, Object> fields = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                fields.put("Name", "Ashish");
                // fields.put("akshayg__Donor_Location__Latitude__s",
                // Double.toString(plat));
                // fields.put("akshayg__Donor_Location__Longitude__s",
                // Double.toString(plong));
                RestRequest request = null;

                try {
                    request = RestRequest.getRequestForUpdate(
                            getString(R.string.api_version), objectType,
                            objectId, fields);
                    // Toast.makeText(this, "Location Updation has started",
                    // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // printHeader("Could not build update request");
                    printException(e);
                    return;
                }

                client.sendAsync(request, new AsyncRequestCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(RestRequest request,
                            RestResponse result) {

                        // Toast.makeText(this,
                        // ""+Double.toString(plat)+","+Double.toString(plong),
                        // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        try {
                             //Toast.makeText(this, "Location Updated",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            Log.v("X",
                                    "Response:inside onSuccess() " + result.toString());
                            /*JSONArray records = result.asJSONObject()
                                    .getJSONArray("records");
                            for (int i = 0; i < records.length(); i++) {
                                // listAdapter.add(records.getJSONObject(i).getString("Name"));
                                // listAdapter.add(records.getJSONObject(i).getString("akshayg__Phone_Number__c"));
                                // listAdapter.add(records.getJSONObject(i).getString("akshayg__Donor_Location__Latitude__s"));
                                // listAdapter.add(records.getJSONObject(i).getString("akshayg__Donor_Location__Longitude__s"));
                            }
                        */ 
                        }
                        catch (Exception e) {
                            onError(e);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Exception exception) {
                        Log.v("X",
                                "Response: " + exception.toString());

                        // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        // MainActivity.this.getString(ForceApp.APP.getSalesforceR().stringGenericError(),
                        // exception.toString()),
                        // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                });
            }

        }

        private void printException(Exception e) {
            String err = "Error: " + e.getClass().getSimpleName();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), err, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Location Updation has stoped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

the toasts till "inside detectLocation" are popped up and log entries made till

```
04-04 00:42:34.687: V/X(10217): Response:After lm1.requestLocationUpdates
```

but beyond that the code is just unreachable...
even the GPS sign is shown in action bar but the toast for displaying location is not popped... pls help....!!!

Comment: Are you inside of a building? gps must have a clear view of the sky to work. It will hunt for a signal indefinitely if it cannot see any satelites.

Comment: even if m inside the building 
Log.d("X","Response:inside onLocationChanged ");
it shud should be logged right..?

Comment: no, because you will not ever get an onLocationChanged() callback unless it actually connects to a satelite.

Comment: i tried it going outside, i waited there for 5 mins but stl toast did not pop up...

Answer (score 0):

In `requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10, Two_Min, ll1)` you're passing Two_Min (which you've set to 5*60*1000 = 300000) into the minDistance paramter which should be a number of metres.  Try setting minDistance to 0 instead.

Comment: hi, i did the changes u suggested but its not working...
in fact the GPS symbol from action bar has also disappeared...pls help..

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on in your code, but one thing that might shed some light would be to put logging into the other methods i.e. onProviderDisabled(...),  onProviderEnabled(...), onStatusChanged(...) and see if that tells you what's going on.

Comment: i put logs as you suggested and turns out

04-04 23:33:44.782: V/X(3533): Response:inside onProviderDisabled(String provider)
04-04 23:34:06.873: V/X(3533): Response:inside onProviderEnabled(String provider)

but why is onProviderDisabled() getting called before onProviderEnabled()...?

shud i put the code i want to execute inside Disabled() or Enabled()..?

Comment: I don't think you should put any code inside the enabled/disabled functions, apart from code to save the enabled/disabled state of each provider.  Did you check the provider string, it's not in your log?  In any case, once it tells you that the GPS provider is working then presumably you are getting calls to onLocationChanged(..).

Comment: yes, i checked provider string and its GPS. i tried getting lastknownlocation() and passing it to to the onlocationchanged() but its always null. what could be the problem..?

Comment: According to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation(java.lang.String) if the lastknownlocation is null then the provider is disabled.